# Login to redirect to other page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I cannot redirect from the Login page to the `/profile` page after clicking the `Login` button. How can I fix that?

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function checkLogin() {
    const loginFormUser = document.getElementById("login-form-user");
    const loginFormPassword = document.getElementById("login-form-password");
    const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
    loginButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const username = loginFormUser.username.value;
      const password = loginFormPassword.password.value;

      if (username === "toilacoder" && password === "123456") {
        return history.push("/profile");
      } else {
        return history.push("/home");
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={checkLogin}>
      <h2>Please login to get access to your profile.</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="login-form-user" />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Your password"
        id="login-form-password"
      />
      <button id="login-form-submit" type="submit">
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: I'll do that. thanks, sir!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript remove `.username` and `.password` as its a typo. You can also use refs for this https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: It did not redirect me to the /profile but it reload and give me "/login?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an event argument to your `checkLogin` function.
You will then use it to prevent the default behavior on form submission by calling the `preventDefault` function.

Also, the `addEventListener` was useless, since you are already triggering the `checkLogin` function on the button click.

Finally, you can retrieve the values from the DOM element without specifying the `username` and `password` attributes after you have retrieved the elements with `getElementById`.

Try to change your code like this:

```
function checkLogin(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const loginFormUser = document.getElementById("login-form-user");
  const loginFormPassword = document.getElementById("login-form-password");

  const username = loginFormUser.value.trim();
  const password = loginFormPassword.value.trim();

  if (username === "toilacoder" && password === "123456") {
    history.push("/profile");
  } else {
    history.push("/home");
  }
}
```